# searching by date as a single element instead of Year, Month and Day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I'm trying to add a date search to a small rails project. To do this I'm using a form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>     
        <%= select_date Date.today, prefix: :start_date %>  
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name =>nil %> 
    </p>
<%end%>
```

This results in a url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_date[year]=2013&start_date[month]=10&start_date[day]=11
```

is there any way to combine the search params in the url into a single Date, so that the url looks like this?:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&start_date=2013-06-01
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? `params[:start_date]` will be a `Date` anyway. `start_date=2013-06-01` will be a `String` and you will have to parse it yourself (including error handling).

Comment: it's part of an assignment that specified the url format to have date params like above. I think because the url needs to contain 2 dates and an integer as search parameters

Comment: Than use an `text_field`instead of the `select_date` and improve the UI with something like http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.